# Error on installing module

Tags: 7

I've got Drupal 7.20 on my server (skyislands.pl). I wanted to install (from my local computer) Wysiwyg module (http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), but I see this error. My server is running on EHCP. How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks for any help,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a permissions problem. You will be able to install the module by downloading it and putting it into your sites/all/modules folder

Comment: Should I change permissions of sites/all/modules ?

Comment: I am not sure, I don't use the automatic module download thing that is in Drupal 7. I always just download modules and copy them across, or use drush.

Comment: Ok, Should I send extracted archive or don't extracted ?

Comment: extracted, so the path to the module info file is sites/all/modules/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.info